# Python data structure to mimic relational databases

Tags: python, list, search, dictionary, set

I would like to store a lot of instances of some data in python. Each record has the following fields:
username, address, salary etc...

The username should be unique. I do a lot of searches.

Currently I am using a list of dictionaries, but when I insert a new item I iterate the list and check the username of each dictionary, which is O(n). Searching is O(n) too. How could I achieve that there is an index on usernames, and make the search time O(logn)?

Comment: Generally, the way to get to `O(log n)` is with binary searching, which suggests ordering your list alphabetically by username. If usernames are unique, why not just use an outer dictionary, though?

Comment: Why not use a dictionary with the usernames as keys?

Comment: Why mimic a relational database, when you can use a relational database (like [sqlite](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)).

Comment: Dictionary with username as a key gives you O(1) lookup time.

Comment: i guess you have to provide a sample of your data that you want to use. I cant imagine how you would get a db with unique username. Doesnt seem right and probably this is a bad idea. If this is a really small project you have already one or two answers on the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a dictionary of dicts?

The top-level dictionary could be addressed by the username and the other dicts can be the same you have now.

A dictionary can also be scanned threw (d.values()) -- the only disadvantage is, that you can't depend on the ordering.

Of course that is not a DB behavior, but in most cases good enough and very fast -- the access via dict is O(1).

Of course you could use sqlite -- but when you just want to access via username and scan the entries, you are much faster (both in development- and runtime speed).

Answer (score 1):

You could alternatively actually use a relational database. The [sqlite](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) module allows for databases in memory:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
# ...
conn.close()
```